# Apache POI can't format filled cells as numeric

Tags: java, excel, exception, apache-poi

I am trying to change CellTypes of **already filled** Cells in Apache POI, but I keep getting an IllegalStateException. The problem should be reproduceable using POI(-ooxml) **3.16**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    //Setting up the workbook and the sheet
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet s = wb.createSheet();

    //Setting up the CTTable
    XSSFTable t = s.createTable();
    CTTable ctt = t.getCTTable();
    ctt.setId(1);
    ctt.setName("CT Table Test");
    ctt.setRef("A1:B2");
    CTTableColumns cttcs = ctt.addNewTableColumns();
    CTTableColumn cttc1 = cttcs.addNewTableColumn();
    cttc1.setId(1);
    CTTableColumn cttc2 = cttcs.addNewTableColumn();
    cttc2.setId(2);

    //Creating the cells
    XSSFCell c1 = s.createRow(0).createCell(0);
    XSSFCell c2 = s.getRow(0).createCell(1);
    XSSFCell c3 = s.createRow(1).createCell(0);
    XSSFCell c4 = s.getRow(1).createCell(1);

    //Inserting values; some numeric strings, some alphabetical strings
    c1.setCellValue(/*12*/"12"); //Numbers have to be inputted as a string
    c2.setCellValue(/*34*/"34"); //for the code to work 
    c3.setCellValue("AB");
    c4.setCellValue("CD");

    //With those lines, the code would also crash
    //c1.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
    //c2.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);

    //On write() it produces a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell"
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.xlsx");
    wb.write(fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    wb.close();
}
```

Also, when not setting any CellValue for c1 and c2, you **can actually** set their CellType to *NUMERIC* and suddenly the code works again. It also works without the CTTable.

Any ideas or workarounds? Or is it a bug of POI (since it tries fetching a string value from any Cell regardless of its CellType)?

Comment: Why are you setting cell types explicitly? Why not just let Apache POI auto-detect the type based on the values supplied?

Comment: @Gagravarr as stated in the code comments, numbers being "autodetected" will crash the code! It doesn't matter if I go for `c1.setCellValue("12"); c1.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);` or just `c1.setCellValue(12);`. Fact is, if in the end, when i want to write my workbook to a file, there is any numeric Cell in a CTTable, it will throw an IllegalStateException :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Apache POI 3.17 beta 1 or later for this to work (or a nightly build from after 20170607)

If you do, you can also make your code significantly simpler and cleaner too. As shown [in the `testNumericCellsInTable()` unit test](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/TestXSSFTable.java), your code could simplify to something like:

```
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet s = wb.createSheet();

    // Create some cells, some numeric, some not
    Cell c1 = s.createRow(0).createCell(0);
    Cell c2 = s.getRow(0).createCell(1);
    Cell c3 = s.getRow(0).createCell(2);
    Cell c4 = s.createRow(1).createCell(0);
    Cell c5 = s.getRow(1).createCell(1);
    Cell c6 = s.getRow(1).createCell(2);
    c1.setCellValue(12);
    c2.setCellValue(34.56);
    c3.setCellValue("ABCD");
    c4.setCellValue("AB");
    c5.setCellValue("CD");
    c6.setCellValue("EF");

    // Setting up the CTTable
    Table t = s.createTable();
    t.setName("TableTest");
    t.setDisplayName("CT_Table_Test");
    t.addColumn();
    t.addColumn();
    t.addColumn();
    t.setCellReferences(new AreaReference(
            new CellReference(c1), new CellReference(c6)
    ));
```

(Unlike your problem code, this does a mixture of integers, floating point numbers and strings for the table headers, to show the various options)

Comment: I think your code misses some castings and has wrong method names, but besides that, it works in the new version! Damn it POI...

Comment: My code was cut and paste from a passing unit test in Apache POI! You need to be using a version from today onwards though...